# mysql query inserting 3 duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following code to record hits into a views table, but when I load this page the MySQL query inserts 3 rows at a time, so 1 hit means 3 hits. I am trying to figure it out, but can't get any luck.

```
    $width = 16;
    $height = 16;

    $id = 30

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


    //count views

    global $db;


    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.DB_PREFIX.'views (invoice_id, ip, user_agent) 
                                               VALUES ("' . $id . '",
                                                "' . ip2long($ip) . '",
                                                "' . $user_agent . '")';

$db->query($sql);

//display image
header( "Content-type: image/png" );
$img = imagecreate($width, $height);
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 238, 238, 238);
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

If I replace the display image code with a simple `echo "Successfully done!"`, the problem is fixed and it only inserts one row.

**mysql rows**

```
id     invoice_id    ip         user_agent    dnt
35     22           2058457116     Mozilla/5.0   2013-04-17 11:55:12
34     22           2058457116     Mozilla/5.0   2013-04-17 11:55:12
33     22           2058457116     Mozilla/5.0   2013-04-17 11:55:11
```

Comment: Are you sure you're only calling this script once? Maybe outputting `"Successfully done!"` breaks something somewhere else making it so you call it only once.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen yes only once, i am debugging by calling its direct url in browser.

Comment: Need more data to figure out whats going on: 1.Can you paste the three records getting created each time 2.Exactly which lines of image code are you replacing and do you get successfully done echoed correctly?

Comment: Try changing $sql to something else like $sql_2. Maybe $sql is being passed into another query further down the script

Comment: @Raidenace 1. I am pasting row in question 2.image generation code(from header().... imagedestroy()) and yes i get successfully done echoed correctly

Comment: Where is your display image code? Sounds like the culprit may be in there.

Comment: @richelliot i have tried that too

Comment: @Revent see question and check underneath //display image

Comment: @seoppc Didnt see the rows in the question..

Comment: do a die() after the imagedestroy and see if it still creates duplicate entries

Comment: @Raidenace same issue, even after die() at end

Answer (score 0):

There's no way the script can insert three rows.

So the only possibility is that the script is run three times.

I would recommend you to check the web server log for accesses to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a templating engine or a CMS of some sort? for example, i've tried Drupal before  and due to the hooks capability of the system, a file might be called more than once.. same as a templating engine. This could be the problem. also, echoing something might stop the other scripts from running because of an error linked to the 'headers already sent' case. that's why even if you do a die() at the end, it will still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can your please tell what os and browser you are using for testing.
I once had a similar problem while trying with safari in IOS device.
My code was for downloading an audio. For all OS it was working fine. But for safari in IOS device download code was getting executed multiple times.
Pls check this on other browser and let us know the results.